# Error "Parameter count mismatch" in QSqlTableModel

Tags: python, pyqt5, qsqltablemodel

Please help me to fix a "Parameter count mismatch" exception in python.

I'm using `QSqlTableModel` connected to a `sqlite3` database. My connection works fine and also my data are properly set: when I insert a record, after starting the program, everything work fine, but when I try to insert a new record, I receive the error "Parameter count mismatch". The following code throws the exception:

```py
        if not self.table_model.submitAll():
            error_message = f"Error Customer Model: {self.table_model.lastError().text()}"
            raise CustomModelError(error_message)
```

`self.table_model.submitAll()` fails. The more full `python` code is:

```py
    def update_customer(self, customer_id, data):
        try:
            self.db_model.open_connection()
            row = self.find_row_by_customer_id(customer_id)
            record = self.set_db_record(data, row)
            self.table_model.setRecord(row, record)
            self.confirm_database_changes()
            return customer_id
        finally:
            self.db_model.close_connection()

    def find_row_by_customer_id(self, customer_id):
        row = -1
        for i in range(self.table_model.rowCount()):
            if str(self.table_model.data(self.table_model.index(i, 0))) == str(customer_id):
                row = i
                break
        return row

   def confirm_database_changes(self):
        if not self.table_model.submitAll():
            error_message = f"Error Customer Model: {self.table_model.lastError().text()}"
            raise CustomModelError(error_message)
        self.table_model.database().commit()
        self.table_model.select()
        self.select()
```

As you can see in the `confirm_database_changes` method, I refresh the model after inserting the new record, but the error still exists.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a more comprehensive [mre], most importantly `set_db_record()`. Also, check the return value of `setRecord()`, which is probably `False` in your case.

Comment: It's somewhat bizarre that you choose to iterate over the rows to find the id. Why not just query the db? It also looks totally broken that `find_row_by_customer_id` returns `-1` on failure rather than raising an error. Why would you want to pass a known invalid id to those other methods?

Comment: Thanks, for your answers. I changed the code after your suggestions, but the error sometimes still happens sometimes. Anyway, I still used method find_row_by_customer_id because I want to update the record into self.table_model (that's the QSqlTableModel) and then I want to update the database using method confirm_database_changes.